# Deletar table>tr com Ajax e PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Fala galera, to com uma duvida aqui.. quero poder deletar uma linha da tabela com Ajax apenas clicando em um botão sem precisar carregar a tela.. já pesquisei e tentei fazer mais não deu certo.. tenho o seguinte código html:

```
<tr>
    <td><?= $client['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $client['email']; ?></td>
    <td><?= $client['tell']; ?></
    <td class="text-center"><button id="delete" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button></td>
</tr>
```

e java script:

```
$("#delete").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "id="+id,
        url: "/removeClient",
        dataType: "json"
    });

    return false;
});
```

a parte do php eu resolvo.. quero apenas receber um $_POST['id'] e passar para o methodo que ira deletar o registro. Agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver aqui da seguinte forma..

```
$(function() {
    $(".delete").click(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var id = element.attr("id");
    var info = 'id=' + id;

    if(confirm("Deseja realmente Deletar cliente id:   " + id)) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/removeClient",
            data: info,
            success: function () {
            }
        });

        $(this).parents("#show").animate({backgroundColor: "#003"}, "slow").animate({opacity: "hide"}, "slow");
    }

    });
});
```

esta funcionando e deleta a row apos a o confirm retornar true, porem gostaria de saber como posso personalizar esse confirm, ou utilizar algum modal.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro coloque um id na sua tr, e muda o delete de id para classe, e coloco um atributo data com o id no button

```
   <tr class="tr_<?= $client['id']; ?>">
        <td><?= $client['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $client['email']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $client['tell']; ?></
        <td class="text-center"><button data-id="<?= $client['id']; ?>" id="delete" class="delete glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button></td>
    </tr>
```

Ai faça a requisição, e faça com que o php devolva 1 para deletado, e 0 para erro.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "pagina.php",
        data: {id: id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data)
        {
            var retorno = data;

            if(retorno === 1){
               $('.tr_'+id).empty().hide();
            }else{
               alert('erro no php');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Não testei o código, mas acho que se não estiver certo, ta bem próximo.

Comment: Cara fiz igual teu código mais não funcionou, e nem retorna nada no console nem o ('erro no php').. tentei alterar algumas coisas mas nada.. x=

Comment: Testei e o código é isso mesmo, você ta fazendo alguma coisa errada, provavelmente está faltando alguma coisa na tabela, ou o caminho para o php não está correto.

Answer (score 0):

Na resposta do AP ....... porem gostaria de saber como posso personalizar esse confirm, ou utilizar algum modal.

1. As Bibliotecas

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   ```
2. SCRIPS

   ```
   //função disparada ao clicar no botão relativo a linha
   $(function() {
       $(".delete").click(function(){
           var element = $(this);
           id = element.attr("data-id");
               if(id){
                   //conteudo do paragrafo <p id="resultado"></p> dentro do modal
                   $("#resultado").html("Tem certeza que quer excluir o id "+id);

                   //abre o modal com a pergunta acima
                   $("#myModal").modal('show');
                }
       });
   });

   //função disparada ao clicar no botão deletar do modal
   function checkDeletar() {
       jQuery.ajax({
       url: "/removeClient"",
       data: 'id=' + id,
       type: "POST",
       success:function(data){

           /* oculta a linha */
           $('.tr_'+data).hide();

           //oculta o modal
           $("#myModal").modal('hide');

       },
       error:function (){
           alert('erro');
       }
       });
   }
   ```
3. HTML

   ```
      <!-- Se esquecer de colocar a tag table o código não vai funcionar -->
      <table ....>
          <tr class="tr_<?= $client['id']; ?>">
               <td><?= $client['name']; ?></td>
               <td><?= $client['email']; ?></td>
               <td><?= $client['tell']; ?></td>
               <td class="text-center"><button data-id="<?= $client['id']; ?>" id="delete" class="delete glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button></td>
           </tr>
       </table>


       <!-- Modal -->
       <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
           <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span>X</span></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                           <p id="resultado"></p>

                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onClick="checkDeletar()">Deletar</button>   

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
       <!-- Modal -->
   ```